# I use yarn add, and nodeJS tells me 'cannot find module' for my whole folder

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules, yarnpkg

I'm building a login web app. The folder name is 'login' I use `yarn add` to initialize my project and add all the packages. When I want to run my project with `node .`, it returns an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/home/mynameis/Documents/tecky-exercises/login'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

[image]

Grateful if you can help me with the error. Why does the error occur in my whole folder rather than particular dependencies?

I suspect the error is related to the location of package.json or tsconfig.json. It's duplicated and I don't know which location is correct.

Comment: ~~can we see your `index.js`?~~ I think you need to run `node .` in `/server` because you don't have `index.js` in your root folder

Comment: @kkesley require('ts-node/register'); require('./main');

Comment: I suspect you need to run it in `./server` folder. so in your **root** folder (which is `login`). run `node ./server`. It will throw an error because you don't have any `node_modules` in `server` folder, though. In that case, run `yarn add` in the `./server` folder

Comment: @kkesley so, should I install all packages again after running in the server folder?

Comment: yes. Or you can move your index.js to the root directory (which is `/login`)

Comment: Thank you, @kkesley. You've solved by problem! One followup question, is it good to delete `package.json` and `yarn.lock` in `/login` to avoid confusion?

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion around [yarn] and [yarnpkg].

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because there's no `index.js` (or `.ts`) in your project's root folder (`/login`).

If you still want to keep your code in `/login/server` folder, you probably want to run the code by using `node ./server`.

Moreover, you need to run `yarn install` in your `/login/server` folder because you have 2 package.json in your project. (it will resolve to the nearest one from your code. In this case, it will try to find `node_modules` in your `/login/server` folder)

To answer your follow up question, yes you can remove either of them. If you remove the package.json in `/login/server`, you need to keep the `/login/node_modules`. If you remove the one in `/login`, you need to keep the `/login/server/node_modules`